# R best way to use quote and unquote macro variable

Tags: r, macros, double-quotes

I have the following code to check if the dataset existed and if the dataset has data, and the problem is coming from the double quote around the macro variable.

```
check_data_ready <- defmacro(tracking_sheet,table_df,table_name,
expr={if (exists(table_df) && is.data.frame(get(table_df)) && dim(table_df)==NULL) {`tracking_sheet$DataReady[tracking_sheet$Table==table_name]<-'Ready'
} else {tracking_sheet$DataReady[tracking_sheet$Table==table_name]<-'Check!'}
                           })

check_data_ready(tracking_sheet,"df","Table")
```

the error msg is

> Error in if (exists("df") && is.data.frame(get("df")) && dim("df") ==

So apparently dim("df") is not working, which should be dim(df). I try to substr the double quote from 2 to 3, but looks like it recognize d as 1 and f as 2, it doesn't count the double quote. I am lost here, how do I make the code working like this

```
if (exists("df") && is.data.frame(get("df")) && dim(df) ==
```

Comment: Where does the `defmacro` function come from? That doesn't appear to be a base R function.

Comment: Why not use `get(table_df)` with `dim()` like you do with `is.data.frame()`?